# Synchronization error while import pst file (Error code 800CCC15-0-0-430)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have exported emails from outlook which is using IMAP protocal with size of 8GB, when i am trying to import the back up file in other PC, i am getting the synchronization error with error code 800CCC15-0-0-430. Please refer the following image to view the error message. Please help me to solve the error.
[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bffl6.jpg)

I also sharing the documentation from microsoft to backup the emails [Back up your email](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-your-email-e5845b0b-1aeb-424f-924c-aa1c33b18833)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**

***Issue*:**

When importing the back up file in other PC, i am getting the synchronization error with error code 800CCC15-0-0-430.

***Solution:***

I have created Gmail account and enabled IMAP and it worked.

Comment: Please note that some of the emails where not synchronised to Gmail account and those emails where successfully imported to local environment from the backup

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any specific operations before the issue occur? Such as creating subfolders in Inbox? If so, please move subfolders outside the Inbox folder and import again to check if there're any differences.

In addition, I found a similar thread as your issue mentioned that it may be affected by the root folder path in Advanced settings, please refer to YukiSun-MSFT's answer in this [thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/74113/outlook-error-synchronizing-folder-800ccc0e-0-0-43.html#:%7E:text=YukiSun%2DMSFT%20answered%20%E2%80%A2%20Aug%2024%202020%20at%201%3A58%20PM%20%7C%20Scotter60%20commented%20%E2%80%A2%20Aug%2028%202021%20at%2011%3A14%20AM).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there is no subfolders

Comment: Have you tried to check the root folder path in Advanced settings as mentioned by YukiSun-MSFT in that thread?

Comment: Anyway thanks for the time. It seems to be working after repair using scanpst but i am not able to access the emails in my localPC (i.e. By opening outlook data file from import/export in the file menu)

Comment: Do you mean that you can import the .pst file to the other PC by using Scanpst and then you can't check the emails in the .pst file, right? If so, it maybe the imported .pst file is currupted. I'm afraid you need to import it again.

Comment: No i just mean PST file is working when connected to Godaddy hosting. But my question is there any way i can open PST file locally.

Comment: To open .pst file, just go to File > Open & Export > Open Outlook Data File in Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for the time. But it was not working

Comment: I have created Gmail account and enabled IMAP and it worked. Anyway thanks

Comment: I'm glad your problem has been solved. I have summarized your reply and written a new answer, would you mind marking it as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.